# How to change the value of a button and to add more buttons to form on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When an element is clicked on my page, I need to change the value of Submit button in this form below to `Edit` and to add two more buttons to it using `$("#submitform").append('');`.

However, it's not the only form on the page and it's inside a `<div>` so I cannot access it using

```
document.submitform.submit.value
```

What other way(s) of accessing this form's input button value I could use?

```
<div id="adds-content" class="switcher-content set1 show">
  <form action='/post' name='submitform' id="submitform" method='post' class='pure-form'>
    <textarea columns="40" rows="4" name='entry[body]' id="statement" placeholder='enter a note'></textarea>
    <input type='submit' name="submit" value="save" class="pure-button pure-button-primary" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: can only be one `id="submitform"` in page so not clear whay you can't access submit. Where are other elements that are being clicked and where is click handling code? Question is incomplete

Comment: Me too, I don't understand. Probably it's because I'm using menus that show/hide the div with that form.

Comment: that doesn't make any sense. Without you showing the code that isn't working nobody can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're already using jQuery on the page, you could use `.val()` to change the button text and `.after()` to add new DOM elements. The code might look something like the following:

```
$('.edit-form').on('click', function(){
    $('.submitform-submit')
        .val('Edit')
        .after('<button>Button 1</button>')
        .after('<button>Button 2</button>');
});
```

See this JSFiddle for a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/p5cy6xv8/

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted to access it without adding the class or id to the button. How do I access a certain button inside a form if it doesn't have an ID?